# Using MFMailComposeViewController to send both HTML and Plain Text versions of email

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How can I use MFMailComposeViewController to send both an HTML and fallback plain text version of an email?  The API has a method for setting the message body as either/or, but not a way to specify both.  I have seen other apps do it (such as Doodle Jump), so it must be possible.

Comment: On closer inspection of Doodle Jump's email, it looks like MFMailComposeViewController actually creates the plain text email automatically by stripping out HTML.  That's okay if I can create an HTML version that looks okay in plain text.  However, it does result in some strange text such as "Click Here" type links that aren't links.

Comment: Ha ha. You know what - I *bought* doodlejump yesterday just to check it was really using MFMailComposer. I didn't get around to checking the output mail. Too busy climbing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considerable investigation, both in code and using Google, I've come to the conclusion that it is not possible to do this via MFMailComposeViewController.  I would love someone to prove me wrong, so if you discover otherwise, I'll be happy to vote your answer up.

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide guesses as I've not tried this.

The documentation says that calls to setMessageBody:isHTML: replace the previous body. Its worth trying two calls - one with isHTML:YES and one with NO, just in case the docs are flakey: but that's pretty unlikely.

If the boundary is constant (I'm hoping it is) I'd say the way to do it would be to send it as HTML and fake the plain text part to the end. You will need to send yourself a HTML email or 3 and check that the boundary *is* constant, and grab it. Then append

```
------=_NextPart_111_2222_11223344.aabbccdd
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Plain text content
```

replacing the NextPart stuff with the real boundary.
If boundary is not consistent, then I have no idea :-) Worth a try maybe ?

Comment: That's a reasonable guess, and I had already investigated both approaches.  The second call just replaces the message body.  The boundary is also generated by the Mail Composer and is not constant, so I can't change that.  Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am doing, the output is fine, i am not able to attach the image, else i would hv shown you guys

```
 NSString *emailBody = @"<HTML><BODY><B>It is raining in sunny California!</B><table><tr><td>row1</td><td>row2</td></tr><tr><td>row3</td><td><b>row4</b></td></tr></table></BODY></HTML>";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```